# Using an associative array where the value type is an instantiation of std.typecons.Nullable

Tags: d

New to D! I have two set functions for inputting key/value pairs into my AA. One that takes just a Key (K) and one that takes a pair (K,V) The one I'm having issues with is

```
struct SMap(K,V) {
    private Nullable!(V)[K] stuff; 

void set(K k){                    //Issue is with this one
    if(k in stuff) 
        stuff[k].nullify;
}

void set(K k, V v){
    if(k !in stuff)
        stuff[k] = v;
```

If I negate the statement, then I run into a Range error. I know that when calling nullify, I wipe out the value paired with 'k' and I believe it sets the isNull to true (if I'm reading the documentation correctly)
How do I insert 'k' as the key with a nullable value?

```
SMap!(int,string) sm;
sm.set(2);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: so my gut feeling is that either the default toHash function doesn't handle this well, or the k there is mutable and changing out from under it. Maybe I can help more later when I get a chance to run it though. You might be able to sidestep it too by doing this: `if(auto ptr = k in stuff) ptr.nullify;` - working via the pointer that `in` returns instead of looking it up again.

Comment: I do know that if it's written as   `if(k !in stuff) stuff[k].nullify;`    works but I will have a range error thrown for any immediate function called in main after this one has returned to main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RangeError` makes a lot of sense for `if(k !in stuff) stuff[k].nullify;`. You're saying 'if there is no element `k` in `stuff`, then do something to it.' If it doesn't exist, you can't do something to it. End of.

More explicitly, what your code does is this:

`if (k !in stuff) {
    auto tmp = stuff[k]; // This line throws RangeError, since there is no element k in stuff.
    tmp.nullify();
    stuff[k] = tmp;
}`

Of course, this isn't what you want, you want to set it to null. May I suggest this:

`void set(K k){ 
    stuff[k] = Nullable!V.init;
}`

Answer (score 1):

The only workable answer that I finally figured out was the following:

```
if(k in stuff)
    stuff[k].nullify;    //I suppose that this part could actually be deleted.
else{
    Nullable!(V)a;       //Create a Nullable object
    a.nullify;           //nullify it but this part may not be needed
    stuff[k] = a;        //Assign to stuff[k] which sets the isNull data field to true
}
```